# 1146 Database Error Python Django

Tags: python, django

I am programming in Django 1.5 with Python 2.7 on Windows Vista. I am trying to create user profiles. However, when 
I visit localhost:8000/admin/home/userprofile, I got the `1146, "Table 'demo.home_userprofile' doesn't exist` error. 
Now I have in `settings.py`:

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'home.userProfile'
```

and in `models.py`, where I have the defining values

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class userProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = url)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length = 30)

    def url(self, filename):
        ruta = "MultimediaData/Users/$s/%s"%(self.user.username, filename)
        return ruta

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

and in `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from demo.apps.home.models import userProfile

admin.site.register(userProfile)
```

I have been mulling this over for a while now. What seems to be wrong?

Comment: If table doesn't exist perhaps you forgot to syncdb or migrate if you are using South or equivalent

Comment: Turns out I only need to type `python manage.py syncdb`. I was following a tutorial and that person did not do it.